# Maven dependencies are not getting downloaded, proxy issues?

Tags: maven, maven-3

Current WinHTTP proxy settings:   Direct access (no proxy server) in windows machine. And in settings.xml as  . But, jars are not getting downloaded and getting below error.

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor fo
```

r org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central
 (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.24.215] failed: Connection timed out: con
nect -> [Help 1]

Comment: Can you ping the repo server?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As per maven documentation we have to add some `settings.xml` with setting in it mentioned here [Guide to proxies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html) .

```
<settings>
   <proxies>
      <proxy>
        <id>example-proxy</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <host>proxy.example.com</host>
        <port>8080</port>
        <username>proxyuser</username>
        <password>somepassword</password>
        <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
      </proxy>
   </proxies>
   .
   .
</settings>
```

Another way to do download dependencies quickly is as follows

```
mvn clean install -DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=myproxy.com -DproxyPort=YourPort
```

the second one works fine for me. Hope atleast one of above solution will work for you hoping your network doesn't have any blocked servers from maven repo.

Comment: Worked after adding proxy details in settings.xml. Thanks

Comment: how to set proxy for org.scalatest  for this dependency

Answer (score -1):

If you have  a antivirus installed in your machine then simply disable that to 10 mins and try to do mvn clean install . All the dependecy from maven repo will download .

This worked for me . Thanks !