# spring-boot-starter-parent 2.3.5.RELEASE not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have a Java 11 project and an Ultimate 2019.2 IntelliJ IDE with a Maven build.

As soon as I pull from the repository, my pom.xml file gives the following error:

```
spring-boot-starter-parent 2.3.5.RELEASE not found
```

in reference to this block of code in the pom.xml file:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

I've tried reimporting my dependencies - no change.

I've also tried doing a clean build.  I get the following error:

```
Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.3.5.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.40.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks much.

Comment: Can you try pinging the server?

Comment: The following question may have some answers for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64697003/project-org-springframework-bootspring-boot-starter-parent2-3-5-release-not

Comment: are you behind a proxy ?

Comment: If you are behind a proxy, maybe this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38329243/maven-dependencies-are-not-getting-downloaded-proxy-issues/38457353) can help you.

Comment: Network issue... failed: Connection timed out: connect..

Comment: Thanks for all of the suggestions.  I am using a proxy, and running the command

mvn clean install -DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=myproxy.com -DproxyPort=YourPort go

did get me further.  The command errored out before completion - but at least I can now do a clean install.

My pom.xml file still shows the same spring-boot-starter-parent 2.3.5.RELEASE not found error though.